# Instantiating a List from a method that returns a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to instantiate a new instance of a list to objects that are received from a method in a different .dll class. When I do this I get a type conversion error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<HelpDeskBusinessDataObject.Employee>
>       to System.Collections.Generic.List<HelpDeskBusinessUserObject.Employee>

Here is how I am instantiating it:

```
public List<EmployeeBusinessUser> GetAll()
{
    EmployeeBusinessData empData = new EmployeeBusinessData();

    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
    List<EmployeeBusinessUser> retEmployees = new List<EmployeeBusinessUser>();

    try
    {
        //Here is where I am trying to get the list assigned to what is 
        //returned from the method call
        employees = empData.GetAll();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorRoutine(ex, "EmployeeUserData", "GetAll");
    }

    return retEmployees;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: the GetAll() method:

```
 public List<Employee> GetAll()
    {
        HelpDeskDBEntities dbContext = new HelpDeskDBEntities();
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        try
        {
            employees = dbContext.Employees.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        return employees;
    }
```

Comment: `HelpDeskBusinessDataObject` != `HelpDeskBusinessUserObject`

Comment: @PSL's suggestion is correct. Also did you try declaring as var?

Comment: I know. I am calling a method in a class called EmployeeBusinessData that is inside of a project called HelpDeskBusinessDataObjects. Supposed to have this method that I have above call the method in EmployeeBusinessData and be able to return a list of employee objects.

Comment: @PSL: there are enough reasons to have them seperate.
AaronG. you could look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to (very easily) convert your DataObject to your UserObject.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply assign two classes in 2 different namespace. You need to have a conversion or translation method to map those two.

Error clearly says it with the namespace.  **HelpDeskBusinessDataObject vs HelpDeskBusinessUserObject**

Cannot implicitly convert type 
`System.Collections.Generic.List<HelpDeskBusinessDataObject.Employee> to System.Collections.Generic.List<HelpDeskBusinessUserObject.Employee>`

Answer (score 0):

EmpData is an instance of EmployeeBusinessData.  employees is a List of Employee.  You cannot simply get all unless method GetAll() returns

```
List<Employee>.
```

Just check your return type from GetAll() and make sure it is returning a List of Employee.

Comment: It is returning a list of employees, which is why I am confused as to why it isn't working.

Comment: What is the namespacing on your Employees?  You're probably using a business object in one instance and a data object in another.  Both are called Employee, but they are not the same type.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the namespacing? I'm still learning VB/C# code so this is all new.

Answer (score 0):

This error simply means you cannot return a List of type HelpDeskBusinessDataObject where   HelpDeskBusinessUserObject is expected. Please post the call to GetAll() method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq in particular [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0) to convert  `HelpDeskBusinessDataObject.Employee` to `HelpDeskBusinessUserObject.Employee`.

For example like that:

```cs
empData.GetAll().Select(e => createBusinessUserEmployee(e)).ToList();
```